# Converting local coordinates into global coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates

Since there aren't any georeferenced points on the site, we're creating a local grid using a few close locations as references as I use a total station to do some measuring.

Aerial photographs can be used to establish the approximate coordinates of these locations, at least accurately enough for our purposes.

How can we use QGIS to convert our local coordinates into UTM or any other type of global coordinates in the easiest way possible?

CAD is presently being used to shift and modify the coordinate values, but that is not the most elegant or efficient approach.

Comment: The most elegant approach would be to measure coordinates in the field, e.g. using a smartphone.

Answer (score 2):

I do this all day long with Excel and AutoCAD Civil 3D, but since you think AutoCAD is not "elegant or efficient", I'll show you how to do this with QGIS.
Use the GeoScience Plugin and select "Create Local CRS..." which takes you to a page where you put in at least 3 tie points. When you hit "Calculate" it gives you a WKT for a Custom Projection. From there you can transform "on the fly" to anything you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I didn't want to sound like that, probably there are a better way to do it in CAD, but what I have been doing until now is just positioning the points by hand on known coordinates. I have tried to use Geoscience pluginh, but I am having an error with all the different CRSs I am trying " AttributeError: type object 'QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem' has no attribute 'WktVariant'". Thanks!!

Comment: Kinda hard to tell what's happening without seeing the data. Please post your drawing or shapefile, and at least 3 tie points.